# Ingresar metadatos desde un select desde wordpress

Tags: base-de-datos, wordpress

les escribo porque tengo un problema como lo dice el titulo para ingresar metadatos en wordpress desde un select. resulta que el select trae contenido de varios plugin como woocommerce y otro que es un plugin de marketplace. el asunto es que logro mostrar en el select las ordenes especificas del usuario que este loguedo para que el seleccione una de ellas y califique a un vendedor, este enviara a dos tablas de las base de datos el review con las respectiva calificacion y el numero de orden en cuestion. Ahora bien en el codigo que realice como dije al principio muestro las ordenes de dicho usuario, pero al enviar el formulario en la base de datos solo me carga la primera orden del usuario pero no la que el seleccionara.

```
introducir el código aquí
<select id="order_select" name="ordeni">



                <?php
                foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
                    $order      = wc_get_order( method_exists( $customer_order, 'get_id' ) ? $customer_order->get_id() : $customer_order->ID );
                    if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '2.7', '<' ) ) {
                        $order->populate( $customer_order );
                    }
                    $order_id   = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order->get_id() : $order->id;
                    $order_number   = $order->get_order_number();
                    $order_number   = preg_replace( '/#([\w-]+)/i', '$1', $order_number );
                    $order_date     = method_exists( $order, 'get_date_created' ) ? $order->get_date_created()->format( get_option( 'date_format' ) ) : date( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) );

                    echo '<option value="' . $order_id . '">';
                        echo __( 'Order #', 'awesome-support-woocommerce' ) . $order_id . ' - ' . $order_date;
                    echo '</option>';

                } ?>

                </select>

            <?php endif;

        }

    endif; ?>

</div>


introducir el código aquí
```

$value) 
{      
  add_comment_meta($value->comment_ID,'new_order_data',$order_id);
}  
  ?>

tuve la idea de introducir el contenido de este select de la manera

```
introducir el código aquí
```

$var = $_POST['$order_id']

y cambiando add_comment_meta($value->comment_ID,'new_order_data',$var);

pero me sale Null en la base de datos.

Comment: Tienes un error de sintaxis, debería ser : `$var = $_POST['order_id']`  sin el $ en order_id

Comment: Muchas gracias por contestar, si tienes razon fue un error cuanto escribi la pregunta pero en el codigo lo tengo como me dices y tampoco me funciona, es más he probado colocando el name:  $var = $_POST['order_id']    o $var = $_POST['ordeni'] que es el valor del name del select sin obtener resultado.

Comment: me he dado cuenta que colocando solo el llamado de la variable para mostrarla como echo con $var = $_POST['ordeni'] tampoco la muestra en echo $var; es como si no guardara el valor por el metodo POST, (estoy realizando las pruebas en localhost )

Comment: Fundamenta esto para depurar: [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/es/function.error-reporting.php), [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ini-set.php) y [print_r](http://php.net/manual/es/function.print-r.php)

Comment: Añade al inicio del script, para mostrar los errores: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors','on');`

Comment: y después, para saber que variables te han llegado:  `print_r($_REQUEST);`

Comment: por cierto, no has especificado [`method`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp) así que por defecto se usará `get`, por tanto debes poner: `$var = $_GET['orderi']`  además de un poquito más de atención ;)

Comment: Gracias por contestar, Fly, tu codigo me mostro algunas variables como no definidas, pero realmente estas no hacian mucho en el codigo en general. con respecto al metodo si lo coloque al principio en el form que lleva todo este codigo, lo que sucede es que copie la parte que me parecio que podia tener el error, por otro lado realice otras pruebas y pude tener un pequeño avance al introducir los datos en el formulario. utilizando dos form diferentes uno para todo el contenido general de ese formulario y otro para el campo adicional que no cargaba

Comment: pero al colocar dos form tengo dos botones submit y no solo que se ve mal estéticamente sino que es poco funcional. tienes alguna idea de como hacer para enlazar dos form con el mismo botón?

Comment: Ni se te ocurra usar esa solución de los dos formularios, el problema debe ser una tontería. Si tienes dificultades con un formulario, imagínate con dos y haciendo un malabares en medio.... Coloca el código completo, sino estaremos dando vueltas sin sentido y después a ver si logramos encontrar el error. Muestra también los valores resultantes así como cualquier error que salga por pantalla.

Comment: Perfecto te copio el código completo

Answer (score 0):

```
     <?php

 global $WCMp, $wpdb;

  if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly
 }

 if (isset($queried_object->term_id) && !empty($queried_object)) {
$vendor = get_wcmp_vendor_by_term($queried_object->term_id);
$shop_name = $vendor->page_title;
$vendor_id = $vendor->id;
$count = $vendor->get_review_count();
$is_enable = wcmp_seller_review_enable($queried_object->term_id);
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$reviews_lists = $vendor->get_reviews_and_rating(0);
 }

 ?>

 <div class="wocommerce" >
 <div id="reviews" >
    <div id="wcmp_vendor_reviews">
        <?php if (isset($is_enable) && $is_enable) { ?>
            <div id="review_form_wrapper">
                <div id="review_form">
                    <div id="respond" class="comment-respond">
                        <?php if ($vendor->id != get_current_vendor_id()) : ?>
                            <h3 id="reply-title" class="comment-reply-title"><?php
                                if ($count == 0) {
                                    echo sprintf(__('Be the first to review “%s”', 
 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'), $shop_name);
                                } else {
                                    echo sprintf(__('Add a review to “%s”', 'dc- 
  woocommerce-multi-vendor'), $shop_name);
                                }
                                ?> </h3>                
                            <form action="" method="post" id="commentform" 
  class="comment-form" novalidate="">
                                <p id="wcmp_seller_review_rating"></p>
                                <p class="comment-form-rating"><label for="rating"><? 
  php echo __('Your Rating', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?></label>                 
                                    <select name="rating" id="rating">
                                        <option value=""><?php echo __('Rate...', 
 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?></option>
                                        <option value="5"><?php echo __('Perfect', 
  'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?></option>
                                        <option value="4"><?php echo __('Good', 'dc- 
  woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?></option>
                                        <option value="3"><?php echo __('Average', 
'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?></option>
                                        <option value="2"><?php echo __('Not that 
 bad', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?></option>
                                        <option value="1"><?php echo __('Very Poor', 
'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?></option>
                                    </select></p>
                                <p class="comment-form-comment">
                                    <label for="comment"><?php echo __('Your Review', 
 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?> </label>
                                    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" cols="45" 
 rows="8" aria-required="true">  </textarea>



                              </p>  






                              <p class="form-submit">
                                    <input id="wcmp_vendor_for_rating" 
   name="wcmp_vendor_for_rating" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $vendor_id; ?>"  >
                                    <input id="author" name="author" type="hidden" 
  value="<?php echo $current_user->display_name; ?>" size="30" aria-required="true">                     
                                    <input id="email" name="email" type="hidden" 
 value="<?php echo $current_user->user_email; ?>" size="30" aria-required="true">


                                    <input name="submit1" type="button" id="submit" 
 class="submit" value="<?php _e('Submit', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor') ?>">

                                </p>                
                            </form>


    <form action="" method="post">      
                                <?php           






global $wp_query;

$order_id    = isset( $wp_query->query['view-order'] ) ? $wp_query->query['view- 
order'] : '';
$field_id    = 'wpas_' . $field['name'];
$value       = wpas_get_cf_value( $field_id, $post_id );
$label       = wpas_get_field_title( $field );
$field_class = isset( $field['args']['field_class'] ) ? $field['args']['field_class'] 
: ''; ?>

<div <?php wpas_get_field_container_class( $field_id ); ?> id="<?php echo $field_id; 
?>_container">

    <?php if ( ! is_admin() || current_user_can( $field['args']['capability'] ) ) : ? 
 >

        <?php if ( $order_id ) { ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $field_id; ?>" value="<?php echo 
 $order_id; ?>" />
        <?php } else {

            $customer_id = is_admin() ? get_post_field( 'post_author', get_the_ID() ) 
 : get_current_user_id();

            $customer_orders = get_posts( array(
                'numberposts' => -1,
                'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
                'meta_value'  => $customer_id,
                'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types( 'view-orders' ),
                'post_status' => array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() )
            ) );

            if ( $customer_orders ) : ?>
                <label style="display:block;">Agregue la orden que desea calificar 
  del vendedor</label>
                <select id="order_select" name="ordeni">



                <?php
                foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
                    $order      = wc_get_order( method_exists( $customer_order, 
  'get_id' ) ? $customer_order->get_id() : $customer_order->ID );
                    if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '2.7', '<' ) ) {
                        $order->populate( $customer_order );
                    }
                    $order_id   = method_exists( $order, 'get_id' ) ? $order- 
  >get_id() : $order->id;
                    $order_number   = $order->get_order_number();
                    $order_number   = preg_replace( '/#([\w-]+)/i', '$1', 
  $order_number );
                    $order_date     = method_exists( $order, 'get_date_created' ) ? 
    $order->get_date_created()->format( get_option( 'date_format' ) ) : date( 
   get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( $order->order_date ) );

                    echo '<option value="' . $order_id . '">';
                        echo $order_id;
                    echo '</option>';

                } ?>

                </select>

            <?php endif;

            }

          endif; ?>

           </div>
         </select><input name="agregar" type="submit" value="Agregar"> 
      </form>                       

        <?php   

     if(isset($_REQUEST['agregar'])) 
      {
      $orderid = $_POST['ordeni'];

       echo $orderid. "fue Agregada con exito";

      $fetch_comment = get_comments($comment);
      foreach ($fetch_comment as $key => $value) 
      {      
      add_comment_meta($value->comment_ID,'new_order_data',$orderid);
     }  
      }
        ?>






                            <?php endif; ?>

                    </div><!-- #respond -->
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        <div id="comments">
            <?php
            if ($count > 0) {
                $start = 0;
                $posts_per_page = get_option('posts_per_page');
                $total_pages = ceil($count / $posts_per_page);
                ?>
                <h2><?php printf(_n('%s review for %s', '%s reviews for %s', $count, 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'), $count, $shop_name); ?>    </h2>
                <form id="vendor_review_rating_pagi_form" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="pageno" id="wcmp_review_rating_pageno" value="1" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="postperpage" id="wcmp_review_rating_postperpage" value="<?php echo $posts_per_page; ?>" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="totalpage" id="wcmp_review_rating_totalpage" value="<?php echo $total_pages; ?>" >
                    <input type="hidden" name="totalreview" id="wcmp_review_rating_totalreview" value="<?php echo $count; ?>" > 
                    <input type="hidden" name="term_id" id="wcmp_review_rating_term_id" value = "<?php echo $queried_object->term_id; ?>">
                </form>
                <?php
                if (isset($reviews_lists) && count($reviews_lists) > 0) {
                    echo '<ol class="commentlist vendor_comment_list">';
                    $WCMp->template->get_template('review/wcmp-vendor-review.php', array('reviews_lists' => $reviews_lists, 'vendor_term_id' => $queried_object->term_id));
                    echo '</ol>';
                    if ($total_pages > 1) {
                        echo '<div class="wcmp_review_loader"><img src="' . $WCMp->plugin_url . 'assets/images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="ajax-loader" /></div>';
                        echo '<input name="loadmore" type="button" id="wcmp_review_load_more" class="submit wcmp_load_more" style="float:right;" value="'.__('Load More', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor').'">';
                    }
                }
            } elseif ($count == 0) {
                ?>
                <p class="woocommerce-noreviews"><?php echo __('There are no reviews yet.', 'dc-woocommerce-multi-vendor'); ?> </p>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>  
        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Como puedes ver es un poco largo el codigo, aqui te adjunte el que tenia los dos formularios que fue el que medio funciono, porque aunque cargaba los datos los duplicaba en los registro anteriores, es decir si se introducía el dato de una presente orden se duplicaba la informacion en todas las anteriores de la tabla. la unica diferencia entre esta opcion de los dos formularios y la anterior es que todo el contenido del segundo formulario estaba antes del boton del primer formulario.

Comment: Por favor, no añadas respuestas si son ediciones de la pregunta original, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/238325/edit) la pregunta y añade todo lo que necesites al final de la pregunta original, si indicas claramente que es una edición cualquiera puede seguir la evolución del tema sin perderse.

Comment: lo tendré en cuenta para el futuro, lo siento.